# How to convert URL array to string array?

Tags: ios, swift

I have several locally saved .txt files that are loaded and saved as a URL array like:

```
func loadShortStories() {
    shortStories = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "txt", subdirectory: nil)!
}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destinationViewController = segue.destination as? ListVC {
        destinationViewController.shortStories = shortStories
    }
}
```

And then in the next ListVC where I load them into a tableview, I have:

```
var shortStories: [URL] = []
```

I need to hardcode the specific order of the .txt files but need to convert them to a string first. How can I do this?

I tried

```
let shortStoriesString = shortStories.absoluteString but it does not work.
```

Added:

I do remove pathextension and lastcomponent in cellForRowAt method with:

```
shortStories[indexPath.row].deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent
```

But before I do that, I want to hardcode the order in which the .txt files are being loaded into the textview because its random and I would like them to be listed in a specific non algorithmic way, like:

```
let order : [String] = [ "story7.txt", "story3.txt", "story1.txt", "story4.txt" ]
```

. That's why I am trying to convert the URL into a string.

Comment: What do you mean by locally saved? Where are those files located?

Comment: In my app bundle

Comment: I wouldn't convert your URL array to string array. Keep your urls and use them when populating your table view. Regarding your file names you can use `FileManager.default.displayName(atPath: yourURL.path)` or get your url resourceValues for the localizedNameKey

Comment: The FileManager.default.displayName(atPath: yourURL.path) will let me hard code the order of .txt files for the tableView? Could you give me a quick example of how to write this? I have never seen this one before.

Comment: You can custom sort your urls using the url lastPathComponent or the displayName. `urls.sorted { $0.lastPathComponent < $1.lastPathComponent }
`  or `urls.sorted { FileManager.default.displayName(atPath: $0.path) < FileManager.default.displayName(atPath: $1.path) }`

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
let shortStoriesString = shortStories.map {$0.lastPathComponent}
```

As `shortStories` is an array not a single object

Comment: I am not sure but OP probably doesn't want to show the whole file url in his table view. It would be better to just display the url lastPathComponent or get the fileURL resource values for the `.nameKey`

Comment: For those who haven't used map before, it's a way of transforming one array to another one, element by element. In this one, each element is being converted to the result of calling `.absoluteString` on that same element.

Comment: @LeoDabus I think this solution works. The OP wrote that they needed to convert convert a "URL array" to a "string array" and this would definitely be the first step.

Comment: Why not just pass the url array itself?

Comment: @LeoDabus since the op will look to these comments , then here are all the properties that may fit the real need of him that we don't know https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/1779984-absolutestring

Comment: look at the question **I would like them to be listed in a specific non algorithmic way, like:** `let order : [String] = [ "story7.txt", "story3.txt", "story1.txt", "story4.txt" ] `

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the name of the file, use it to generate the url.

```
let stories: [String] = [ "story7", "story3", "story1", "story4" ]

let storyURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: stories[index], withExtension: "txt")
```

Comment: Thanks. I just tried this and I get this error  - Cannot convert value of type '(Any) -> Int' to expected argument type '(UnboundedRange_) -> ()'